# Cantor set symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm trying to write about the Cantor set in LaTeX. It can be represented by a weird "C" symbol. It can be seen in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set

I can't find the name of it anywhere. Does anyone know what it is and how to typeset it in LaTeX?

Thanks.

Edit: By going into the edit mode of the wikipedia article I found that the command is "\mathcal{C}". Still trying to find out the name though.

Comment: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html suggests `\mathcal{C}`.

Comment: `\mathcal{C}` .